# How to measure nano-amps easily?

Tags: measurement, current-measurement

I want to measure the stand-by current of the PIC, but my DVM has minimum 2000micro (u) amper switch. It shows 0 micro amps when in 2000 u amps mode. Without building circuit a complex (more than 3-4 components) circuit, how can I measure nano amps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put a suitable resistor in series, and your DVM (in voltage mode) over the resistor.

For instance, a current of 100 nA through a 1M resistor will give you 0.1V. Check the input impedance of your DVM, for this to work it must be >> 1M. You will probably need a switch to short the resistor for the period that your target is not yet in low-power mode.

Another way would be to use a known-sized capacitor as power supply and see how fast it discharges. Again, your measurement instrument must have a high impedance, otherwise it will  disturb the measurement. You might get around this by connecting the voltmeter to measure  the voltage only at specific moments.

Comment: I think it safe to say "You **will** need a switch to short the resistor . . ."

Comment: If you know the input impedance of your multimeter, you may not even need a separate resistor. Just stick the DMM in series, in voltage mode.

Answer (score 5):

Get one of those: https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/eevblog/current-gold-precision-multimeter-current-adapter. It has also been reviewed on the EEVBlog.

Comment: It was made by the EEVBlog guy!!!

Comment: I've watched his videos on low current measurements ... wish I had known how to do it 10 years ago ...

Answer (score 0):

TIA opamp circuit with a FET opamp.
opa134 has ~pA of bias current.
10-100 Meg ohm feedback resistor.
Bipolar power supply.